Prophet Forecast Not Reflecting Expected Behavior with External Regressors
I'm using Prophet to forecast moisture sensor data for multiple farmers, with the data recorded at 15-minute intervals. I've added external regressors (Rain and Temperature) to the model. Below is a sample of my data:

Training Data-frame (Machine_Learning_Data.csv):

Farmer_Id   ds  y   Rain    Temperature
47  2023-05-12 10:00:00 -2.0039 0   36
47  2023-05-12 10:15:00 -2.1148 0   36
47  2023-05-12 10:30:00 -2.1702 0   36


Prediction Data-frame (predict.csv):

Farmer_Id   ds  Rain    Temperature
47  2024-08-23 00:00:00 0   25
47  2024-08-23 00:15:00 0   25
47  2024-08-23 00:30:00 0   25
47  2024-08-23 00:45:00 832000  25
47  2024-08-23 01:00:00 0   25

My expectation is that after adding water at 2024-08-23 00:45:00, the predicted moisture should increase. However, the model predicts the value to decrease significantly. The output I am getting is:
ds                     yhat  
2024-08-23 00:00:00 -14.055044  
2024-08-23 00:15:00 -14.119256  
2024-08-23 00:30:00 -14.177260  
2024-08-23 00:45:00 -40.969768  
2024-08-23 01:00:00 -14.273644  
2024-08-23 01:15:00 -14.313095  
2024-08-23 01:30:00 -14.348438  
2024-08-23 01:45:00 -14.381592  
2024-08-23 02:00:00 -14.414816  

output I am expecting is:
ds                     yhat  
2024-08-23 00:00:00 -14.055044  
2024-08-23 00:15:00 -14.119256  
2024-08-23 00:30:00 -14.177260  
2024-08-23 00:45:00 -40.969768  
2024-08-23 01:00:00 -14.273644  
2024-08-23 01:15:00 -14.313095  
2024-08-23 01:30:00 -14.348438  
2024-08-23 01:45:00 -14.381592  
2024-08-23 02:00:00 -14.414816  

Issues:

Prediction Direction: The sensor value moves in the wrong direction after water(832000-Rain) is added(-40.969768). Could this be due to the negative values in the dataset?
Impact on Time-Series: Adding water only affects the current row, while I expect the effect to persist over subsequent time steps. Is this a limitation of the Prophet model, or am I handling the external regressor incorrectly?

Here is a simplified version of my code for reference:

import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet
import pickle

class MultiFarmerForecasting:
    def __init__(self, farmer_data_list):
        self.farmer_data_list = farmer_data_list
        self.models = {}

    def create_model(self, changepoint_prior_scale=10, 
                     seasonality_prior_scale=100.0):
        model = Prophet(
            changepoint_prior_scale=changepoint_prior_scale,
            seasonality_prior_scale=seasonality_prior_scale
        )
        # Add regressors for Rain and Temperature
        model.add_regressor('Rain', prior_scale=0.5, standardize=True, mode='additive')
        model.add_regressor('Temperature', prior_scale=0.1, standardize=True, mode='additive')
        return model

    def clean_invalid_dates(self, df, date_column='ds'):
        try:
            df[date_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_column])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Cleaning invalid dates: {e}")
            df = df[pd.to_datetime(df[date_column], errors='coerce').notna()]
        return df

    def add_lagged_features(self, df, water_column='Rain', lag=10):
        df = df.copy()
        df[f'Lagged_Water_{lag}_mins'] = df[water_column].shift(lag)
        return df

    def train_model(self, farmer_id, farmer_df):
        # Clean invalid dates
        farmer_df = self.clean_invalid_dates(farmer_df)
        # Add lagged features
        farmer_df = self.add_lagged_features(farmer_df, water_column='Rain', lag=10)
        
        # Remove rows with NaN values due to shifting
        farmer_df = farmer_df.dropna()

        # Create and train the model
        model = self.create_model()
        model.fit(farmer_df)
        self.models[farmer_id] = model

    def predict(self, farmer_id, future_df):
        model = self.models.get(farmer_id)
        if model is None:
            raise ValueError(f"No model found for farmer {farmer_id}")

        # Add lagged features to future data
        future_df = self.add_lagged_features(future_df, water_column='Rain', lag=10)
        
        future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods= 1)
        # Predict using the model
        forecast = model.predict(future_df)
        return forecast[['ds', 'yhat']]

    def save_model_and_forecast(self, farmer_id, forecast):
        # Save the model
        model_filename = f"farmer_{farmer_id}_model.pkl"
        with open(model_filename, 'wb') as model_file:
            pickle.dump(self.models[farmer_id], model_file)
        print(f"Model saved as {model_filename}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('Machine_Learning_Data.csv')
    farmer_data_list = {farmer_id: farmer_df for farmer_id, farmer_df in df.groupby('Farmer_Id')}
    multi_farmer_forecasting = MultiFarmerForecasting(farmer_data_list)
    
    # Train the model for each farmer
    for farmer_id, farmer_df in farmer_data_list.items():
        multi_farmer_forecasting.train_model(farmer_id, farmer_df)

    # Predict for future periods
    future_df = pd.read_csv('predict.csv')  # Load future data with Rain and Temperature columns
    farmer_id = 47  # Example farmer ID
    predictions = multi_farmer_forecasting.predict(farmer_id, future_df)
    print(predictions)
    forecast_filename = f"farmer_{farmer_id}_forecast.csv"
    predictions.to_csv(forecast_filename, index=False)
    print(f"Forecast saved as {forecast_filename}")

    # Save the model and forecast
    multi_farmer_forecasting.save_model_and_forecast(farmer_id, predictions)

    # Plot the forecast vs actual data
    actual_df = farmer_data_list[farmer_id]  # Actual data

How to address these issues?

any one know the reason please ?
